# How can I list best selling products in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to consider best-selling product in this loop :

```
<?php
    $args4 = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'product_cat' => 'cat', 'order' => 'DEC' );
    $loop4 = new WP_Query( $args4 );
    while ( $loop4->have_posts() ) : $loop4->the_post();?>
    <div class="view-back">
        <span><?php echo $product->get_categories( ) ?></span>
        <span><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span>
        <a class="pb" href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop4->post->ID ) ?>">more<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <span class="pt"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
    </div>
    <?php $image4 = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($loop4->post->ID), 'single-post-thumbnail' );?>
    <img src="<?php  echo $image4[0]; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $loop4->post->ID; ?>">
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Perhaps, this link may help you: https://wpza.net/displaying-best-sellers-without-a-plugin-in-woocommerce/ as a clear guide. Using `total_sales` as a `meta_key`, whilst ordering by `meta_value_num`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Solution 1:** Add This plugin [WP woocommerce best selling products by category](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sp-woocommerce-best-selling-products-by-category/)

**Solution 2:** For retrieving the best buying products in WooCommerce we are using wp_query manipulation with meta_key as “total_sales” and orderby “meta_value_num”. In short we are displaying products as per the total sales number.Here is the code for this

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_key' => 'total_sales',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
global $product; ?>
<div>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="id-<?php the_id(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">

<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) 
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); 
        else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="product placeholder Image" width="65px" height="115px" />'; ?>

<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
</a>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a hard time trying to get a list of best selling product through the standard loop. But none of the solutions from here and other stackoverflow posts with the same problem do not work for me.
Finally I get result that solve my problem through the custom  query to data base.

```
global $wpdb;


$order_totals = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT kp_posts.ID FROM kp_posts  INNER JOIN kp_postmeta ON ( kp_posts.ID = kp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( kp_postmeta.meta_key = 'total_sales' ) AND kp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND (kp_posts.post_status = 'publish') GROUP BY kp_posts.ID ORDER BY kp_postmeta.meta_value+0 DESC, kp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 16" );


foreach ( $order_totals as $value ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( $value->ID );

    echo $product->get_title();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT post.post_author as user_id ,sum(meta.meta_value) as product_sell FROM wp_posts as post,wp_postmeta as meta WHERE post.post_type = 'product' AND post.ID = meta.post_id AND meta.meta_key = 'total_sales' group by post_author
```

[image]